# Append text after specific text in file with Ant

Tags: java, ant

Is there any method in Ant that you can add text after any spesific text in text file? For example, I want to add an xml line after a `<service>` xml tag.

Answer (score 3):

To modify an XML document, the best method is probably to do an XSL transformation using the [Ant XSLT task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/style.html). The stylesheet for the task you describe sounds like it would be simple, and this Ant task makes it very straightforward to execute.

Answer (score 2):

You can write simple class for append text.
Then you can run it using ant's task 'java'
[ant java task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html)

Comment: seems ok but it would be nice if there are better solutions

Answer (score 1):

For all xmlspecific tasks the use of **[xmltask](http://www.oopsconsultancy.com/software/xmltask/)** is recommended. For simple appending of some xml use the **[echoxml](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/echoxml.html)** task (since Ant 1.7) with attribute append="true"